# Subclass of UIButton connecting to IBAction of parent View Controller using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

Disclaimer: I'm new to Interface Builder, so it's possible I'm using it entirely incorrectly.

I've created a `NavigationViewController`, attached two `ViewControllers` to it my Storyboard, and added (dragged) a `UIButton` onto the first VC.

I then created a navigation segue on the `UIButton` that navigates between the two VCs. This works as expected.

Where things fall apart, is when I try to use a custom subclass of `UIButton` that I created: the segue is never fired.

- In my `UIButton`'s property inspector, I set the Custom Class to my custom class name.
- I added a couple of user defined runtime attributes to the `UIButton`.

The UIButton header looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RSButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat touchAlpha;

@end
```

And the UIButton implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    self.highlighted = YES;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.04
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                    animations:^{
                        if (self.touchAlpha && self.touchAlpha < 1.0)
                        {
                            self.alpha = self.touchAlpha;
                        }
                    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = NO;
    [self resetToDefaultState];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.highlighted = NO;
    [self resetToDefaultState];
}

- (void)resetToDefaultState
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                  duration:0.12
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                animations:^{
                    if (self.alpha < 1)
                    {
                        self.alpha = 1.0;
                    }
                } completion:nil];
}
```

Interestingly enough, I can see what the problem is: I've overridden the `touchesBegan/touchesEnded` events, and now the segue stuff isn't firing.

What I can't figure out is how to trigger the attached segue action programmatically?

- `performSegueWithIdentifier` isn't available to run on `[self]`, and
- `[self performSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:self)];` would suggest I need to know what the segueId is before I fire it.

Comment: A simpler approach might be to override `setHighlighted:` to call super and change the alpha level.  It would be an isolated override in a single location instead of being spread out over several method calls.  By not overriding touchesEnded, you don't lose it invoking your target action (which is what Matteo's answer fixes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method, call:

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]
```

So:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]

    //Your code
}
```

or:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Your code

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]
}
```

Do the same in touchEnded etc.

**IMPORTANT:**
Remember to call the method on the `superclass` using `super` when you override important and standard methods like those. 
It's the same that you do when you call init on your subclass:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        //your code
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: so when you touch the button your code work? just the segue doesn't work?

Comment: did you called super also in touchEnded etc?

Comment: It worked, but I typed in touchesBegan instead of touchesEnded the first time around, hence why it didn't work. Thanks for your help!